# flot order bars prevent from overlapping

Tags: jquery, flot

How can i make the legends from overlapping. When i try to increase width it is still the same

https://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/g4tfz1c7/2/

I am using 10 series. Please see jsfiddle

```
var options = {
  "series": {
    "lines": {
      "show": false,
      "fill": true,
      "steps": false
    },
    "bars": {
      "show": true,
      "fill": 1,
      "align": "center",
      "barWidth": 0.13,
      "lineWidth": 0
    }
  },
  "xaxis": {
    "ticks": [

    ]
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "tickDecimals": 0,
    "minTickSize": 10
  },
  "grid": {
    "clickable": true,
    "hoverable": true
  },
  "legend": {
    "noColumns": 4
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Numbers of Series) * barWidth` must be smaller than one to avoid overlapping, so for 10 series you could use

```
barWidth: 0.09
```

See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yfe0vfg/).

Comment: will thjis be correct way to work it out `(datasets.length-1)/100`?

Comment: @bonez No, the formula would be `1/(datasets.length+1)`.